# XCode 12.5 - Can't add Apple ID

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode12, xcode12.5

I am attempting to add an Apple ID using Xcode 12.5. When I click the + button -> Click apple id -> Modal dissapears and then nothing happens. I've restarted it multiple times. I tried to import developer accounts from another machine and it will they will appear in the list but stay in a Loading state.

Has anyone seen this? Where do I look at logs for this sorta thing?

Comment: is this only happen in some machines or all machine you have?

Comment: Had exactly the same issue after adding a capability to an app ID (online); a reboot worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it resolved by restarting my computer. I'm not sure why nothing else would work but it got me past it.

Comment: I try to restart my computer but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I've faced multiple issues of that kind (including infinite uploading to the test flight / inability to sign in to already added acc).
The solution was to delete all network settings as described here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/284588/225828 & restart mac.